# cordova / phonegap remote content plugins not working ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i make a cordova ios app using only 2 additional plugins:

- com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
- org.apache.cordova.console (output console.log() in xcode)

i'm using cordova 4.1.2

when the app content point on local index.html everything works fine

config.xml

```
    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
```

but when the content come from a remote url:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
    <content src="http://192.168.115.179/app/index.php" />
    <access origin="*" />
```

the app starts and opens the remote website but the plugins doesnt work.
console.log() messages don't show up in xcode and the barcode view doesnt appear. There are no js errors and xcode show also no errors.

index.php html:

```
<body>
...
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$ProjectWebPath}/sources/interfaces/lead/www/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$ProjectWebPath}/sources/interfaces/lead/www/js/barcodescanner.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{$ProjectWebPath}/sources/interfaces/lead/www/js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
</html>
```

it seems that the js files where not correct included but the pathes are right and i did the **same** app with this method last year and it worked (Cordova Version 3.x).

Anyone an idea what is wrong?

thanks

Comment: ok i understood without any errors it is pretty difficult to help - but is it still (Cordova 4+) possible to use plugins like barcode for remote content??

Comment: the problem is that the cordova.js cant be loaded remotly. in any browser the file is loaded correct and an alert on top gives an output. the compliled version does not gives the alert output. But why? is there any way to load the cordova.js from the app file system and the content from remote host?

Comment: the safari js console said ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
global code barcodescanner.js:119
index.js:22init i think thats because cordova.js not loaded correctly before...

Answer (score 1):

found the failure. pointing on the not platform specific cordoba.js and so the cordoba_plugin.js had not the right plugin pathes

Comment: i dont get it, can i have some example of the final code you are using ?